# Proof of cut elimination

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I am reading [Proofs and types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/prot.pdf) and am blocked at the proof of cut elimination in sequent calculus (chap 13). I don't see either how the cuts are being [pushed up above the preceding steps to the top of the proof](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~jks/LogicNotes/Cut.html) as most key cases have replacements with cuts at the same level ($R \implies$). In any event, what is the proof of the base case of the induction (i.e. cut elimination at the top of the proof)?

Comment: See page 108 : the proof is by a "double" *induction* using the *degree* of a *cut rule* and the *height* of a proof. The start is from the bottom of the proof tree, showing how to eliminate the "final cut".

Comment: The proof is detailed (and boring); you can compare with some other textbooks with more details. See Sara Negri & Jan von Plato, [Structural Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZvACGkn9138C&pg=PA35) (2001), page 35, or Gaisi Takeuti, [Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=Idl6K-W69NYC&pg=PA21) (2nd ed - 1987), page 21.